# Defining message types directly in Python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a Python script to synthesize a rosbag from data files generated outside of ROS.

It would be easiest to be able to define the ROS message types within my Python code, rather than have to write standalone `.msg` definition files and re-generate them over and over again as I iterate on the script.

What would this entail? I'm fine with importing from `genmsg` or `genpy`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390862/defining-message-types-directly-in-python/) by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2021-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
from genpy.dynamic import generate_dynamic
msgs = generate_dynamic('pkg/Msg', 'string data\n')
```

Here `msgs` is a dictionary whose keys are message type names and values are classes that can be used for serialization.

It is possible to pass secondary definitions for dependencies of `pkg/Msg` at the same time. They need to be delimited by a line of 80 `=` characters, then a line that is written `MSG: pkg/Dep`, then the fields.

---

Originally posted by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) with karma: 130 on 2021-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1